# Select columns that have boolean values but not recognized by Pandas as boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subset a dataset into another dataframe that only has boolean data fields (True/False).  The best way to do this is to subset the dataframe by the bool dtype; however, I have NA values in the dataframe, so pandas does not recognize the columns as boolean.  I've also tried to apply a filter on 'True' (string) values or True values (boolean), to no avail.  Any thoughts?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RefID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Lastname': ['Bluejay', 'Westie', 'Tiger', 'Dodo'],
    'Firstname': ['Cantankerous', 'Joy', 'Fifi', 'Mo'],
    'Age': [4, 24, 3, 11],
    'Data': [np.nan, 'False', 'True', 'True'],
    'Graph': [np.nan, 'True', 'False', 'False'],
    'ML': [np.nan, 'False', 'True', 'True']})
```

The desired output is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [np.nan, 'False', 'True', 'True'],
    'Graph': [np.nan, 'True', 'False', 'False'],
    'ML': [np.nan, 'False', 'True', 'True']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to the desired output and the comment below, the question is much clearer. The following snippet can easily give you a list of the columns names which include 'True'-'False' strings.

```
my_list = []
for col_name in df.columns:
    for record in df[col_name]:
        if record == 'True' or record == 'False':
            my_list.append(col_name)
            break

print(my_list)
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking to do - since I have more than 700 columns, I need Python to recognize which are boolean, without having to go in and define the columns myself.  Added the desired output for more clarity.. thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer.  Note that the `break` keyword help preventing extra loops. Also, you can subset your dataframe using `print(df[my_list])`

Answer (score 0):

it's not because you have Na values (pandas can infer object type even with Na values ), your problem is because you have Strings and not bools

if your df is like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RefID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Lastname': ['Bluejay', 'Westie', 'Tiger', 'Dodo'],
    'Firstname': ['Cantankerous', 'Joy', 'Fifi', 'Mo'],
    'Age': [4, 24, 3, 11],
    'Data': [np.NaN, False, True, True],
    'Graph': [np.NaN, True, False, False],
    'ML': [np.NaN, False, True, True]})
```

than pandas will automatically infer "Data" , "Graph", and "ML" as bools:

```
df.Data == True

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: Data, dtype: bool
```

try to convert "True" to True before creating the Dataframe

So you can try this solution to convert only boolean columns from string to boolean :

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

def str_to_bool(x):
    try : 
        return bool(strtobool(x))
    except :
        return x

data = {
    'RefID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Lastname': ['Bluejay', 'Westie', 'Tiger', 'Dodo'],
    'Firstname': ['Cantankerous', 'Joy', 'Fifi', 'Mo'],
    'Age': [4, 24, 3, 11],
    'Data':    [np.NAN,'False', 'True', 'True'],
    'Graph': [np.NAN, 'True', 'False', 'False'],
    'ML': [np.NAN, 'False', 'True', 'True']}

new_data = {k: list(map(lambda x :  str_to_bool(x), v ))  for k, v in data.items() }

df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

and as you can see now the Data column is a boolean :

```
df.Data==True

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: Data, dtype: bool
```